# Laravel considering variable as column name in query builder

Tags: laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.5 and checking event checking if slot available between 2 times using this query:

```
$schedules->where('id', $id)
                ->wherebetween($date, ['start','end'])
                ->orwherebetween($endTime, ['start','end'])
                ->orwherebetween('start', [$date,$endTime])
                ->orderBy('start')->get();
```

getting this error

> "message": "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   '2019-03-06 13:00:00' in 'where clause'

Comment: Use `whereRaw()`

Answer (score 1):

its because the 1st parameter should be the name of the column:

you should change your code to:

```
->wherebetween('column name', ['1st date','2nd date'])
->orwherebetween('column name', ['1st date','2nd date'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed that by adding `DB::raw()` [read more](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#raw-expressions)

```
$schedules->where('id', $id)
                ->wherebetween(DB::raw($date), ['start','end'])
                ->orwherebetween(DB::raw($endTime), ['start','end'])
                ->orwherebetween('start', [$date,$endTime])
                ->orderBy('start')->get();
```